# How to get the feature importance of ranklib generated random forests model?

Tags: random-forest, gini

Using [ranklib](https://sourceforge.net/p/lemur/wiki/RankLib/)'s learning to rank random forests generates an xml-like model. Ranklib has a tool that provides features' frequency which cannot necessarily be considered as feature importance.

How can I get the **Gini feature importance or Gini index** of random forests generated by ranklib? How to parse the tree generated?

Found in the Sourceforge discussion forum that [you need to parse the model file yourself](https://sourceforge.net/p/lemur/discussion/ranklib/thread/7c2bc138/#6c94/b195).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I, personally, had a lot of struggles to get the Gini importance of features from a ranklib random forest and finally succeeded. Here I share the [Github repository](https://github.com/sorooshsorkhani/RankLib-Gini) I made to solve the problem.

You can do it by running this command (use python3):

`python Gini.py <num_features> <path_to\training_data> <path_to\RF_model> <trees directory> <output_file>`

Please see the repository for more details on how to do it.